# How do you get multiple p tags from a div using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**not getting all the p tags, think there are 19 and the count is only for 5, and the print statement only prints the first one
i created the 'data; list just to show what is actually counted and grabbed**

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

link = 'https://www.landsoftexas.com/property/647-acres-in-Burnet-County-Texas/10898818/'
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers) #get the link
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') #read the url page and create a soup object
for acres in soup.find_all('div', {'class': ['_395a0']}):
     data.append((len(soup.find_all('p')), print(soup.find('p').text)))```

**Here is the HTML**:

<div class="_395a0"><section aria-label="Property Description" class="d19de"><h1 class="b442a"> The Cimarron Ranch </h1><p class="d19de">A multi-generational, luxury ranch estate in the Texas Hill Country with over a mile of sandy banks on the Colorado River. The diverse landscape ranges from silty loam soil, improved grazing pastures, cedar filled outcroppings providing cover for wildlife, to gorgeously manicured paddocks, a Pecan bottom down by the River, beach-like waterfront of the Colorado, and on up to high hilltops with spectacular views of the river and surrounding Hill Country. The main home, designed by renowned architect Sinclair Black, sits at one of the highest points of the ranch at 820 foot elevation. With a horse-shoe shape and large, open wrap-around patios, each room in the home feels as though it is its own private residence. Every detail was thoughtfully selected from the lueder stone patios, Cypress wood trim &amp; ceilings, to the exquisite pool area. Guests can be comfortably accommodated with 2 guest houses or bring their RV to one of the 4 hook-ups. A truly iconic Texas Hill Country property masterfully designed to create a stunning and elegant ranch lifestyle within minutes of the bustling town of Marble Falls or just an hour from Austin-Bergstrom International Airport.
</p><p class="d19de">
</p><p class="d19de">Overview:
</p><p class="d19de">
</p><p class="d19de">~ 647 +/- acres, high-fenced
</p><p class="d19de">~ Approximately 1/2 mile on the Colorado River with beautiful sandy beaches
</p><p class="d19de">~ Approximately 1 1/2 miles on both sides of Hamilton Creek
</p><p class="d19de">~ Main Home - 10,084 +/- square feet, 5 bed / 5.5 bath
</p><p class="d19de">~ Beautiful Swimming Pool overlooking the river and Hill Country
</p><p class="d19de">~ Sport Court
</p><p class="d19de">~ Horse Barn - 200' x 70' , 20 stalls, wash/farrier station, tack room, office
</p><p class="d19de">~ 8 separate paddocks with covered areas and irrigation
</p><p class="d19de">~ Riding Arena
</p><p class="d19de">~ 4 RV Hookups
</p><p class="d19de">~ "Granny's House" - 1,804 square feet, 2 bed / 2 bath overlooking the horse paddocks and gorgeous sunsets
</p><p class="d19de">~ "The Bunkhouse" - 3,063 square feet, 4 bed / 3 bath, sunroom/sleeping porch overlooking the Colorado River
</p><p class="d19de">
</p><p class="d19de">Co-Listed with DMTX Realty Group</p><span tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-pressed="true" class="_22a5f">- Show Less</span></section></div>
````

Answer (score 0):

Content of website is provided dynamically, but you can access a script tag that holds the structured data with `json.loads()`:

```
json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text)['description'])

 #output
'A multi-generational, luxury ranch estate in the Texas Hill Country with over a mile of sandy banks on the Colorado River. The diverse landscape ranges from silty loam soil, improved grazing pastures, cedar filled outcroppings providing cover for wildlife, to gorgeously manicured paddocks, a Pecan bottom down by the River, beach-like waterfront of the Colorado, and on up to high hilltops with spectacular views of the river and surrounding Hill Country. The main home, designed by renowned architect Sinclair Black, sits at one of the highest points of the ranch at 820 foot elevation. With a horse-shoe shape and large, open wrap-around patios, each room in the home feels as though it is its own private residence. Every detail was thoughtfully selected from the lueder stone patios, Cypress wood trim & ceilings, to the exquisite pool area. Guests can be comfortably accommodated with 2 guest houses or bring their RV to one of the 4 hook-ups. A truly iconic Texas Hill Country property masterfully designed to create a stunning and elegant ranch lifestyle within minutes of the bustling town of Marble Falls or just an hour from Austin-Bergstrom International Airport.\r\rOverview:\r\r~ 647 +/- acres, high-fenced\r~ Approximately 1/2 mile on the Colorado River with beautiful sandy beaches\r~ Approximately 1 1/2 miles on both sides of Hamilton Creek\r~ Main Home - 10,084 +/- square feet, 5 bed / 5.5 bath\r~ Beautiful Swimming Pool overlooking the river and Hill Country\r~ Sport Court\r~ Horse Barn - 200\' x 70\' , 20 stalls, wash/farrier station, tack room, office\r~ 8 separate paddocks with covered areas and irrigation\r~ Riding Arena\r~ 4 RV Hookups\r~ "Granny\'s House" - 1,804 square feet, 2 bed / 2 bath overlooking the horse paddocks and gorgeous sunsets\r~ "The Bunkhouse" - 3,063 square feet, 4 bed / 3 bath, sunroom/sleeping porch overlooking the Colorado River\r\rCo-Listed with DMTX Realty Group'
```

**Note** *Question do not contains an expected output, so this is just an example, you have to adjust it to your needs.*

You can extract/separate the list like entries with `strip('\r')`.

#### Example

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

URL = 'https://www.landsoftexas.com/property/647-acres-in-Burnet-County-Texas/10898818/'
r = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text)['description'].split('\r')
```

#### Output

```
['A multi-generational, luxury ranch estate in the Texas Hill Country with over a mile of sandy banks on the Colorado River. The diverse landscape ranges from silty loam soil, improved grazing pastures, cedar filled outcroppings providing cover for wildlife, to gorgeously manicured paddocks, a Pecan bottom down by the River, beach-like waterfront of the Colorado, and on up to high hilltops with spectacular views of the river and surrounding Hill Country. The main home, designed by renowned architect Sinclair Black, sits at one of the highest points of the ranch at 820 foot elevation. With a horse-shoe shape and large, open wrap-around patios, each room in the home feels as though it is its own private residence. Every detail was thoughtfully selected from the lueder stone patios, Cypress wood trim & ceilings, to the exquisite pool area. Guests can be comfortably accommodated with 2 guest houses or bring their RV to one of the 4 hook-ups. A truly iconic Texas Hill Country property masterfully designed to create a stunning and elegant ranch lifestyle within minutes of the bustling town of Marble Falls or just an hour from Austin-Bergstrom International Airport.',
 '',
 'Overview:',
 '',
 '~ 647 +/- acres, high-fenced',
 '~ Approximately 1/2 mile on the Colorado River with beautiful sandy beaches',
 '~ Approximately 1 1/2 miles on both sides of Hamilton Creek',
 '~ Main Home - 10,084 +/- square feet, 5 bed / 5.5 bath',
 '~ Beautiful Swimming Pool overlooking the river and Hill Country',
 '~ Sport Court',
 "~ Horse Barn - 200' x 70' , 20 stalls, wash/farrier station, tack room, office",
 '~ 8 separate paddocks with covered areas and irrigation',
 '~ Riding Arena',
 '~ 4 RV Hookups',
 '~ "Granny\'s House" - 1,804 square feet, 2 bed / 2 bath overlooking the horse paddocks and gorgeous sunsets',
 '~ "The Bunkhouse" - 3,063 square feet, 4 bed / 3 bath, sunroom/sleeping porch overlooking the Colorado River',
 '',
 'Co-Listed with DMTX Realty Group']
```

Comment: Got the following error : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Are you sure to getting a propper result from your request? Take a look into your soup does it contain the Information?

Comment: it does have the proper content, not sure why it's not working

Comment: some of the error: JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-37616922baa9> in <module>
      7 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
      8 
----> 9 json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text)['description'].split('\r')

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and

Comment: more:   356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:

Comment: THE REST: --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: can you you use a raw soup object with json.loads?